# Let's get critical: Aug 2014 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Eclipse plugin to add "open the current folder in a file browser" feature](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/9681/eclipse-plugin-to-add-open-the-current-folder-in-a-file-browser-feature)

**Net Score: 11** (Excellent: 12, Satisfactory: 14, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Super-lightweight cloud based text editor](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/9794/super-lightweight-cloud-based-text-editor)

**Net Score: 8** (Excellent: 8, Satisfactory: 19, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Find dead code in a C program by runtime analysis](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/7176/find-dead-code-in-a-c-program-by-runtime-analysis)

**Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 8, Satisfactory: 14, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [Send a file to Google Search by Image search from the Windows Explorer context menu](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/7396/send-a-file-to-google-search-by-image-search-from-the-windows-explorer-context-m)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 9, Satisfactory: 13, Needs Improvement: 5)

---

- [Tool for drawing diagrams](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/9739/tool-for-drawing-diagrams)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 7, Satisfactory: 21, Needs Improvement: 4)

---

- [Free program to remove hidden files from USB sticks](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/9914/free-program-to-remove-hidden-files-from-usb-sticks)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 19, Needs Improvement: 4)

---

- [Changing the transparency of a program's window(s) whenever I start it](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/7565/changing-the-transparency-of-a-programs-windows-whenever-i-start-it)

**Net Score: -4** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 14, Needs Improvement: 7)

---

- [Database/Scripting Language suggestion for a project involving heavy inserts?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/7474/database-scripting-language-suggestion-for-a-project-involving-heavy-inserts)

**Net Score: -6** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 11)

---

- [Easy Web interface development framework](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/7318/easy-web-interface-development-framework)

**Net Score: -6** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 16, Needs Improvement: 9)

---

- [Skype replacement for text chatting](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/7219/skype-replacement-for-text-chatting)

**Net Score: -12** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 18)

---

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of questions on SO about recommending the 'best' software for a purpose which are closed. Some may not be suitable for softwarerecs, but regarding those that are, they should be migrated here.